# How are builds deployed into QA->Staging->Production for ASP.NET Web Applications?

Tags: asp.net, build-process, build, version-control

Secondary questions are

1. How do we best utilize SCM in the build process?
2. How are code files labed and branched?
3. Should we the .csproj and .sln files for build? How flexible are these when deploying to several environments? I know these are msbuild files. But
   as we add new files, this can become a bottlenect of updating and maintaining these .csproj files in SCM.
4. How is rollback done in case of failed builds that QA missed testing etc,etc.,
5. Are there any good articles on the build process?

This is more a question on the process and less on the choice of automated build tools. Please share your build process. I would like to get an end-to-end view 
from developers checking-in to Going Live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous Integration: Improving Software Quality and Reducing Risk

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321336380](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321336380)

book's website is here:

http://www.integratebutton.com